# Use SKSpriteNode as button to transition from GameScene to UITabBarController

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uitabbarcontroller, segue

I have a `UITabBarController` that has two items, the first one being a calendar which is just a `UIWebView`. The second item brings in a SpriteKit game scene and hides the tab bar (The game needs to be full screen).

I have an `SKSpriteNode` image that when tapped, I'd like the view to change back to the calendar view (the first tab bar item).  I've searched for a way to do this and have tried various suggestions I've found here on StackOverflow, but nothing is working. The app crashes with the error

> "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional"

I understand what that error means, just not why I'm getting it.  Here is the relevant code (part of which I got from here while trying to figure this out):

In GameScene.swift:

```
weak var viewController: GameViewController!

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch:UITouch = touches.first! as UITouch
    let positionInScene = touch.locationInNode(self)
    let touchedNode = self.nodeAtPoint(positionInScene)

    if let name = touchedNode.name {
        if name == "exit" {
            self.viewController.gameOver()
            self.removeFromParent()
            self.view?.presentScene(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

In GameViewController.swift:

```
var currentGame: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.hidden = true
    if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = false
        skView.showsNodeCount = false

        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill

        scene.viewController = self
        skView.presentScene(scene)
        currentGame = scene
    }
}

func gameOver() {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("backToMain", sender: nil)
}
```

This is the line giving the error:

```
self.viewController.gameOver()
```

Comment: Not related to this crash, but note that `self.removeFromParent()` doesn't have any effect. SKScene is a root node, thus it can be removed from a node tree. The old scene is replaced with a new one ( and `view.scene` is overwritten) when `view.presentScene()` is called and transition to the new scene is finished.

Comment: Thanks, I got that from one of the other similar questions on this site.  Thought it might work, so I threw it in there.  Good to know it won't help my situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct; I think the likely problem is that you are presenting more than one scene without transferring the value of `viewController`. To track this problem down, use the Find navigator (Cmd+3) to search for `presentScene` then ensure each call is *after* you have transferred the value of the `viewController` property across to the new scene.

Answer (score 0):

I think just remove the 'weak' from the declaration of viewController. You can set a breakpoint on the line giving the error and see if viewController has a value (try po self.viewController in the Xcode console).

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't fix the error.  Yes, the self.viewController is nil when it crashes.  I'll keep debugging and learning to see if I can figure it out.